# Return multiple values to main in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to return multiple values to main.For example if I have this perfect number problem. Is it possible to return the perfect numbers to main & print them from there??

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void perfect(int*,int);
    int main()
    {
        int i,arr[10];

        for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
        printf("Enter range");
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        perfect(arr,10);
        return 0;
    }

    void perfect(int *ptr,int size)
    {
        int i=0,j=0,sum=0,res=0;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            sum=0;
            for(j=1;j<=*ptr/2;j++)
            {
                if(*ptr%j==0)
                {
                sum=sum+j;
                }
            }

            if(sum==*ptr)
            {
                printf("%d is perfect",*ptr);

            }
            ptr++;
     }

   }
```

Comment: Where is the point of passing the size to `perfect` if you are not using it? `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`should be `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: @muXXmit2X : that was a typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, and this is indeed already happening.

`arr` *decays* to a pointer type which is passed by value to `perfect`.

You can modify `arr` through pointer arithmetic on `ptr` within your function `perfect`.

Consider using `size_t` as the type for the `size` parameter; it's designed for storing the sizes of arrays. At the call site, you can use the `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` idiom to yield the size. Don't forget to use that parameter value in the function, rather than hardcoding the number 10.

Comment: I did not completely understand your answer... If possible could you kindly please show me the same programmatically!!?